# Can I drink water to which trace minerals drops had been added before receiving Communion?

Tags: catholicism, communion, fasting

Before going to communion I took a sip of water, realizing afterwards that it may have been water to which drops of minerals to prevent cramping had been added the night before. It was too late to spit out. Should I have refrained from receiving communion. I'll mention it to the priest in my monthly confession.

Comment: Is the issue that you drank this mineral water *right before* taking communion?

Answer (score 4):

It's OK to take medicine before receiving communion.

> Canon law states, “One who is to receive the most Holy Eucharist is to abstain from any food or drink, with the exception only of water and medicine, for at least the period of one hour before Holy Communion” (CIC 919 §1). Elderly people, those who are ill, and their caretakers are excused from the Eucharistic fast (CIC 191 §3).

<sup>Source: Catholic Answers' tract ["Who Can Receive Holy Communion?"](https://www.catholic.com/tract/who-can-receive-communion)</sup>

So if it's medicinal, it's OK.  I'm not even certain that even if it wasn't medicinal that it wouldn't be OK since it's basically water.  I'm pretty sure all water has trace minerals except the kind of water you use in humidifiers and you wouldn't want to drink that.

Comment: Medicine and medicinal have to be more clearly defined. Medicinal substances are not necessarily medicine.

Comment: Yes, my medicinal pancakes are not licit to take prior to receiving Holy Communion.

Answer (score 0):

**Can One drink water to which trace minerals drops had been added before receiving Communion?**

Under ordinary circumstances the short answer is **no**.

One has to go to The Apostolic Constitution of His Holiness Pope Pius XII: [Christus Dominus](https://www.papalencyclicals.net/pius12/p12chdom.htm) to get a definitive answer.

> The Apostolic Constitution “Christus Dominus,” issued today by the Sovereign Pontiff Pius XII happily reigning, grants several faculties and dispensations with respect to the observance of the law of the Eucharistic fast. It also confirms, in great measure and substantially, the rules of the Code of Canon Law[26] for the priests and the faithful able to observe that law of the Eucharistic fast. Nevertheless, the favorable first order of this Constitution, according to which **natural water** (that is, **without the addition of any element**) no longer breaks the Eucharistic fast (Const., Rule I), is extended to these also. But, with regard to the other concessions, these can be used only by priests and by the faithful who find themselves in the conditions described in the Constitution, or by those who say evening Masses or receive Holy Communion at such Masses authorized by the Ordinaries within the limits of the new faculties granted to them.

The Code of Canon Law 919 §1 does not say if there is a distinction between prescription medication and over the counter medication.

> [Can.  919](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib4-cann879-958_en.html#TITLE_III.) §1. A person who is to receive the Most Holy Eucharist is to abstain for at least one hour before holy communion from any food and drink, except for only water and medicine.
>
> §2. A priest who celebrates the Most Holy Eucharist two or three times on the same day can take something before the second or third celebration even if there is less than one hour between them.
>
> §3. The elderly, the infirm, and those who care for them can receive the Most Holy Eucharist even if they have eaten something within the preceding hour.

The reason l quoted Pope Pius XII is to show us the ordinary water does not break the Eucharist fast, that is to say without any element being added to it. So of the faithful may be tempted to say that if there are no calories in the water, it must be acceptable. Not so, just because black coffee or tea has no calories in it, then they are okay. Canon Law specifies that water does not break the Eucharist fast, but Pope Pius XII defines what that water is: natural or ordinary water only. No tea, coffee or flavoured waters make the cut on this subject!

- [How Has Canon Law Changed on Fasting Before Communion?](https://canonlawmadeeasy.com/2017/08/31/canon-law-changed-fasting-communion/)

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to my priest and he told me it was ok. I'm glad I didn't  miss communion. That doesn't mean I will purposely drink water to which trace minerals were added. I took a sip from the wrong bottle.
I had put the mineral drops in the water earlier to prevent my feet and hands from cramping.